# Glassfish 3 Simple Application Client JNLP launch exceptions

Tags: java, glassfish, jnlp

I have created a simple EAR the contains a EJB module and a Application Client. When I deploy this app and attempt to run the generated JNLP from the server I get the following exceptions.

```
[#|2011-11-03T08:05:50.975-0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient.org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws|_ThreadID=36;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Adapter[/___JWSappclient/___system] s1as/glassfish/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler$CloseHandler.notifyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler$CloseHandler.remotlyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.BaseSelectionKeyHandler.notifyRemotlyClose(BaseSelectionKeyHandler.java:233)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.notifyRemotelyClosed(OutputWriter.java:353)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:148)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:282)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:898)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:658)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.doWrite(Response.java:685)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.StaticResourcesAdapter.service(StaticResourcesAdapter.java:238)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.processContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.serviceContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.AppClientHTTPAdapter.service(AppClientHTTPAdapter.java:158)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-11-03T08:06:01.493-0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient.org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws|_ThreadID=37;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Adapter[/___JWSappclient/___system] s1as/glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler$CloseHandler.notifyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:94)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler$CloseHandler.remotlyClosed(MonitorableSelectionKeyHandler.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.BaseSelectionKeyHandler.notifyRemotlyClose(BaseSelectionKeyHandler.java:233)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.notifyRemotelyClosed(OutputWriter.java:353)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:148)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:282)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:898)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:658)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.doWrite(Response.java:685)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.StaticResourcesAdapter.service(StaticResourcesAdapter.java:238)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.processContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.serviceContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.AppClientHTTPAdapter.service(AppClientHTTPAdapter.java:158)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

The application seems to work just fine, but when I launch the JNLP I get those errors in my server.log, any ideas? My glassfish server is 3.1.1 build 12. Here is the zipped up sample application. I used Netbeans 7.0.1 to create it [Source Code](https://s3.amazonaws.com/epicpockets_code_sample/EJBAppClientExample.zip)

**EDITED:**
Per Preston's link to a grizzly bug, I tried replacing the grizzly-utils.jar as described in the comments. Now I am getting a slightly different error. I may try pulling down 3.1.2 branch and building it to see if that has any different effect.

```
[#|2011-11-03T09:47:08.296-0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient.org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Adapter[/___JWSappclient/___system] s1as/glassfish/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:72)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:282)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:898)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:658)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.doWrite(Response.java:685)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.StaticResourcesAdapter.service(StaticResourcesAdapter.java:238)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.processContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.serviceContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.AppClientHTTPAdapter.service(AppClientHTTPAdapter.java:158)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]

[#|2011-11-03T09:47:19.361-0600|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient.org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws|_ThreadID=26;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|Adapter[/___JWSappclient/___system] s1as/glassfish/modules/webservices-osgi.jar
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcher.write0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:29)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:72)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:334)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:108)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.OutputWriter.flushChannel(OutputWriter.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushChannel(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:326)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.flushBuffer(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:398)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.SocketChannelOutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(SocketChannelOutputBuffer.java:282)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer$OutputStreamOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:898)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.filters.IdentityOutputFilter.doWrite(IdentityOutputFilter.java:159)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.InternalOutputBuffer.doWrite(InternalOutputBuffer.java:658)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.Response.doWrite(Response.java:685)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.StaticResourcesAdapter.service(StaticResourcesAdapter.java:238)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.processContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:267)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.RestrictedContentAdapter.serviceContent(RestrictedContentAdapter.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.appclient.server.core.jws.AppClientHTTPAdapter.service(AppClientHTTPAdapter.java:158)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
|#]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a [known issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17150). According to this [issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17270) it was resolved in the 3.1.2 branch just a few days ago on 10/21.

Please grab that branch and retry. Good luck.